# combine lucene indexing and traversal in neo4j to give a single resultset

Tags: lucene, neo4j, traversal, breadth-first-search

Is there any way to combine lucene indexing and traversal in neo4j to search the users indexed by their name but the search results should return minimum depth first (or breadth first traversal)..

i.e. say search all users with name "John*" but closeness to a particular user node should be given more priority than others.
i.e. say the particular node is X then the output should be in the following order:

X--JohnG

X------JohnM

X------------------JohnY

and so on...

I am not sure if i should use an evaluator to filter out on names since there may be thousands of nodes and so it does not sound very efficient without indexing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in Cypher? What version of Neo4j do you plan on using?

Comment: I am using RESTapi with neo4jphp which i think directly calls traversal java api.(no cypher or gremlin). Neo4j version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. I do not see anywhere in the REST traversal framework where you can define the Node by Index, only by Node ID. What you'd have to do is use the REST framework to perform the index lookup to get the Node ID, then perform the traversal on that.

Comment: wont that be slow if the index lookup returns hundreds of nodes.

Comment: Yes, but that's the way the normal traversal frameworks anyways, you can only pass in one node at a time.

Comment: any other alternative to do this faster using cypher or sth.

Comment: So you're just looking for a list of the shortest paths between a start node, and an end node? and the "shortest" path is the smallest amount of relationship traversals?

Comment: i only have the start node but the end node is arrived at based on the search text entered by the user (so there may be multiple end nodes depending on number of matches). So i wanted them sorted by the distance between the start node and the end node, closer ones first.

Comment: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-shortest-path does this work? You could use ORDER BY to get them in ascending order.

Comment: thanks but it appears it runs till certain max depth 15 as given in the example, which may not be efficient for getting all matches if i traverse through the entire graph with million node and much more depth. The only solution i can see is to search by traversing the first few depths using normal neo4j traversal and then do an lucene index search for the remaining depths. This way i should have the desired results for the first few depths but will have a general search result at greater depths.